# Unable to Search Against field in Solr

Tags: search, solr, field

I am unable to search against a particular field called doc_id from solr index.
The data i get is from DB2, and doc_id is the PK in the table.

here are the data import and schema xml

Please help

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="jdbc:db2://infbz1051.in.ibm.com:50000/SCION" user="db2admin" password="db2admin" batchSize="10000" readOnly="true" autoCommit="true" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED" connectionTimeout="5000000" />
  <document name="socialpost">        
    <entity name="post" pk="doc_id" query="select d.DOC_ID,d.SRC_DOC_ID,d.PARENT_ID,d.SRC_PARENT_ID,d.AUTHOR_ID,d.FORUM,d.CUSTOMER as customer,d.TEXT as post_text,d.text as raw_text,d.URL as doc_url,d.LIKES,d.FWD,d.COMMENTS,a.AUTHOR_ID,a.AUTHOR_NAME,a.EMAIL as author_email,a.AGE as author_age,a.GENDER as author_gender from DOC_DETAILS d,AUTHOR_DETAILS a where d.AUTHOR_ID=a.AUTHOR_ID" deltaImportQuery="select d.DOC_ID,d.SRC_DOC_ID,d.PARENT_ID,d.SRC_PARENT_ID,d.AUTHOR_ID,d.FORUM,d.CUSTOMER,d.TEXT as post_text,d.text as raw_text,d.URL as doc_url,d.LIKES,d.FWD,d.COMMENTS,a.AUTHOR_ID,a.AUTHOR_NAME,a.EMAIL as author_email,a.AGE as author_age,a.GENDER as author_gender from DOC_DETAILS d,AUTHOR_DETAILS a where  d.AUTHOR_ID=a.AUTHOR_ID AND d.doc_id='${dataimporter.delta.DOC_ID}'  with ur" deltaQuery="select DOC_ID from doc_details where lastupdatedtime &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' with ur">
       <entity name="concept" query="SELECT S.concept as concept FROM SENTIMENT_AND_CONCEPTS S where S.DOC_ID='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="category" query="SELECT ann.doc_id, ann.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES as category FROM annotations ann where ann.annotator_id=125  and ann.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="hcategory" query="SELECT ann.doc_id, ann.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES as hcategory FROM annotations ann where ann.annotator_id=129  and ann.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="tcategory" query="SELECT ann.doc_id, ann.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES as tcategory FROM annotations ann where ann.annotator_id=127  and ann.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="isparent" query="SELECT count(*) as isparent  FROM db2admin.doc_details where doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' and parent_id=doc_id with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="rankscore" query="select c.CATEGORY_RANK_SCORE as rankscore from CATEGORY_ASSIGNMENT_TABLE c,ANNOTATIONS A where a.doc_id=c.doc_id AND a.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES =c.category_name AND a.ANNOTATOR_ID=125 and  a.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="posttype" query="SELECT ann.doc_id, ann.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES as posttype FROM annotations ann where ann.annotator_id=35  and ann.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
       <entity name="sentimentinfo" query="select c.CATEGORY_SENTIMENT as sentimentinfo from CATEGORY_ASSIGNMENT_TABLE c,ANNOTATIONS A where a.doc_id=c.doc_id AND a.ANNOTATIONMETAVALUES =c.category_name AND a.ANNOTATOR_ID=125 and  a.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >
       </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

### Schema.xml

```xml
<field name="doc_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/> 
<field name="customer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="src_doc_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="parentid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="src_parent_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="author_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="forum" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="timeposted" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="post_text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" multiValued="false"/>
<!-- Raw text copy for retrieval convenience --> 
<field name="raw_text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyfield src="post_text" dest="text_raw" />
<field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="likes_fwd_comments" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="lastupdatedtime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: what's ur query? are u sure ur indexing worked fine?

Comment: Yes index is absolutely fine, i am able to search against other fields. My query is i need to search against the doc_id and i am not able to. the field:value combination does not work out.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is pretty literal - the various SQL results from this will have columns like "d.DOC_ID" or "ann.doc_id" ... not "doc_id" as you have in your Solr schema.

You do have things like "as customer" in there on some of your SQL fields, which means THOSE particular fields will work correctly, assuming the document as a whole passes validation - fields marked required (or uniqueKey) are all present, etc.

You might need to have "AS xxx" for EVERY field in your select statements.

If you are searching on fields that are using the "as" syntax, note that most of them are set to type "string".  In the example schema, the "string" type is a StrField, which has no analysis capability and can therefore only do exact entire-field or wildcard matches.  You can't search for a single word in a multi-word string with the StrField type.

Comment: Well, this is what surprises me, I am performing an exact match on the doc_id field.

Comment: Because none of the SQL statements are retrieving a field with the literal name "doc_id", that field isn't going into your index. Your "post" entity query probably needs to start with "select d.DOC_ID as doc_id" instead of just "select d.DOC_ID" for that to work properly.

Comment: Hmm.. this makes sense. Thank you :). So i tried this out. I placed the below line in the data-config.     <entity name="docidq" query="select d.DOC_ID as docidq from DOC_DETAILS d where d.doc_id='${post.DOC_ID}' with ur" >.
                </entity>